# org babel bash blocks - effectively writing non bash code

Tags: org-babel

Something I often do (and I'm hoping other folks do too)
is write a script and run it through a interpreter.

Since I try to use org mode and org babel for scripting and
literate programming, I end up with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output replace
cat << EOF | psql 
SELECT id,name FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY id;    
EOF
#+END_SRC
```

All I have to do is C-c C-c and I have immediate results.

Sometimes it's a snippet of ruby code - piped to the 'bundle exec rails console' command, similar technique as above psql example.

My problem is, it hard to write anything substantial inside the "heredoc" block above because

```
emacs thinks I'm writing bash, when I'm writing sql
emacs thinks I'm writing bash, when I'm writing ruby
```

This means I loose syntax coloring, smart indentation, etc of the ruby/sql mode.
In -nw mode (prelude) bash "herodocs" have a really low-contrast color, making the code I'm writing really hard to see.

I'm guessing a lot of people write code blocks in org mode that are eventually piped to an interpreter for quick feedback based development.
So whats the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Well, you can use another Babel block's source as the value of a variable in a different code block... I think, I even did this once combining JavaScript with HTML in such way... but it was a while ago, I'll need to find my old test examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074967/make-the-source-code-from-one-code-block-the-input-to-another-code-block-in-emac this isn't my example, but I think it was an inspiration for what I did.